# I have a file > 1g, I want to split it into files with 100k lines each

Tags: python

I want to do this in python but I'm stumped. I wont be able to load the whole file into ram without things becoming unstable, so I want to read it line by line... Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?  "read it line by line" seems like the answer right there.

Comment: yeah but I read somewhere that readline() actually loads the entire file into ram.

Comment: @d-c, You should test it.  If you're really concerned, check Python's memory usage when running your program.

Comment: I'm not totally sure about `readline()` but I know for a fact that the `for line in file: ...` construct does not read the whole file into RAM.

Comment: I just checked the source code (for Python 2.6.5) and it appears that `readline` does not read much more than a single line at a time.

Comment: Neither `readline` nor the loop read the whole file into memory at one gulp -- only moderate amounts of buffering are performed (for speed), but we're talking of something like a few KB at most.

Comment: @d-c: you might be confused with [readlines()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines) which *does* read the whole file into a list by default...

Answer (score 16):

If you do absolutely need to split the file, why not just use the *nix `split` utility?

http://ss64.com/bash/split.html

```
split -l 100000 inputfile
```

Comment: because reading a 1G file into memory all at once wouldn't make *nix box 'unstable'. +1 anyways for highlighting the difference between a toy OS and a real OS.

Comment: `split` doesn't read the entire file into memory at once - it's stream-based.

Comment: @Amber  I was implying that the OP is using windows. If the OP was using *nix, there would have been no reference to 'unstable'

Comment: If you are on Windows, you're _still_ better off using split: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm

Comment: Right tool for the job... But it's *not* Python (albeit callable in Python), and it's not portable.

Answer (score 3):

One idea could be the following:

```
import itertools

with open('the1gfile.txt') as inf:
  for i in itertools.count():
    with open('outfile%d.txt' % i, 'w') as ouf:
      for linenum, line in enumerate(inf):
        ouf.write(line)
        if linenum == 99999: break
      else:
        break
```

The `with` statement requires Python 2.6 or better, or 2.5 with a `from __future__ import with_statement` at the top of the module (that's the reason I'm using old-fashioned string formatting to make the output file names -- the new style wouldn't work in 2.5, and you don't tell us what Python version you want to use -- substitute the new style formatting if your Python version supports it, of course;-).

`itertools.count()` yields 0, 1, 2, ... and so on, with no limit (that loop is terminated only when the conditional `break` at the very end finally executes).

`for linenum, line in enumerate(inf):` reads one line at a time (with some buffering for speed) and sets linenum to 0, 1, 2, ... and so on - and we break off that loop after 100,000 lines (next time, the for loop will continue reading exactly where this one left off).

The `for` loop's `else:` clause executes if and only if the `break` within that loop didn't, therefore, if we've read less than 100,000 lines -- i.e., when the input file is finished.  Note that there will be one empty output file if the number of lines in the input file is an exact multiple of 100,000.

I hope this makes every part of the mechanism sufficiently clear for you...?